# curve parameterization

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, curves

I'm doing an exercise and I have a doubt. It's the following:

A parameterization of the curve $C=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},3y-5z+16=0\}$ could be:

a) $C:t \in [0,2\pi] \rightarrow C(t)=(4\cos t, 3+5\sin t, 5+3\sin t).$

b) $C:u \in [0,2] \rightarrow C(u)=(\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{25-(u+3)^2},u,\frac{3}{5}u+\frac{16}{5})$.

c) $C:u \in [-8,2] \rightarrow C(u)=(\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{25-(u+3)^2},u,\frac{3}{5}u+\frac{16}{5})$.

All options verify the relations in $C$, so I don't know which option could be. Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: I don't think it's a dude but a doubt...

Comment: why in c) u gives non real values of $x$?